# How do I assign multiple values in a dictionary in python?

Tags: python-3.x

I am working with object variables based off ICD-9 codes and am trying to create a dictionary which identifies all ICD-9 codes between E880.xx and E888.xx.

I want to code all values between E880.xx and E888.xx as a 1, and all other values as a 0.

I attempted this:

```
fallinjury_Dictionary = {1 : 'E880', 1 : 'E881', 1 : 'E882' ...}
```

but the key gets overwritten every time and I only end up with one value in the dictionary (1 = E888)

I've also tried this:

```
fallinjury_Dictionary = {1 : {'E880' or 'E881' or 'E882' .... or 'E888'}
```

which just doesn't work.

Comment: Would it help to use an array? Like "{1 : [ 'E880','E881' ...], 2 : ...}.

Comment: Dictionary keys are unique and therefore needs to be hashable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dictionaries can only have one value for each key. If you are looking to map the value `1` to `E880` (instead of the other way around), you can do that, but otherwise you can't (uniqueness of keys is in an inherent part of dictionaries).

```
fallinjury_Dictionary = dict.fromkeys(['E880', 'E881', 'E882'], 1)
fallinjury_Dictionary.update(dict.fromkeys(['E880', 'E883'], 0)) # to update values
```

Answer (score 0):

If i got you right it must be "0: 'E901'" for E901

```py
fallinjury_Dictionary = {1 : 'E880', 1 : 'E881', 1 : 'E882', ... 0: 'E901'}

# Instead i would switch the key and the value for this case
fallinjury_Dictionary = {'E880': 1, 'E881': 1, 'E882':1, ... 'E901': 0}

# You could use boolean
fallinjury_Dictionary = {'E880': True, 'E881': True, 'E882': True, ... 'E901': False}
```

You could also think about creating classes.